# Opcache is Enabled, but Opcode Caching says Disabled?

Tags: php, opcode-cache

I've attached a screenshot. Any ideas of what I'm missing?  I've enabled it via `php.ini`, it shows in `phpinfo` as `enabled`, but says `opcode caching is disabled`.  Using PHP 5.5.

[image: PHP Info Image]

Comment: Have you checked the opcache error log as identified in that screenshot? The answer may lie in there.

Comment: I have, and it's empty unfortunately.

Comment: Is this on a Windows platform by any chance? From http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php: "When running PHP on Windows, you need to be running the Webservice (Apache or IIS) as a local administrator in order to allow PHP to create a shared memory segment. If you run your webservice as anything else, OPCache will simply be disabled."

Comment: It's on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Have you restarted the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to this on my own, but I want others to know as well if they run into the issue.

For whatever reason, multiple .ini files were generated for opcache on the server box and they contained the same settings.

I deleted one, re-enabled opcache, and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: Yup, I found `/etc/php.d/10_opcache.ini` which was overriding the `php.ini`